# Getting a real ip of a user via apache_note("GEOIP_ADDR")

Tags: apache

How do I enable apache_note("GEOIP_ADDR"); to get my client's real IP address?

Our website runs via proxy servers and up until last week, we were able to get client's IP via

```
$ip2=apache_note("GEOIP_ADDR");
echo $ip2;
```

For those of you who don't know, this would be a good alternative to `$headers["X-Forwarded-For"]`However we are unable to do that lately.

Here is a list of loaded Apache Modules

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 authn_file_module (static)
 authn_default_module (static)
 authz_host_module (static)
 authz_groupfile_module (static)
 authz_user_module (static)
 authz_default_module (static)
 auth_basic_module (static)
 file_cache_module (static)
 cache_module (static)
 disk_cache_module (static)
 mem_cache_module (static)
 include_module (static)
 filter_module (static)
 deflate_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 env_module (static)
 expires_module (static)
 headers_module (static)
 setenvif_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 proxy_module (static)
 proxy_connect_module (static)
 proxy_ftp_module (static)
 proxy_http_module (static)
 proxy_scgi_module (static)
 proxy_ajp_module (static)
 proxy_balancer_module (static)
 ssl_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 mime_module (static)
 status_module (static)
 autoindex_module (static)
 asis_module (static)
 info_module (static)
 suexec_module (static)
 cgi_module (static)
 negotiation_module (static)
 dir_module (static)
 actions_module (static)
 userdir_module (static)
 alias_module (static)
 rewrite_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 bwlimited_module (shared)
 geoip_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 pagespeed_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

Answer (score 1):

I was missing

```
    GeoIPScanProxyHeaders On
```

in

```
<IfModule mod_geoip.c>
        GeoIPEnable On
        GeoIPScanProxyHeaders On
        GeoIPDBFile /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat MemoryCache
        GeoIPDBFile /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat MemoryCache
</IfModule>
```

which caused the real IP not to show up.

Now this works as it should.